# Office Online Server and Provider Hosted Apps on the same server

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-web-apps, office-integration

I am trying to work on Provider Hosted Apps for few functionalities here and at the same time configuring Office Web App Server. As per the documentation at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219435.aspx#software it says

> You can use physical servers or virtual machine instances, but you can’t install other server applications (such as SharePoint 2013 or SQL Server) on the same server as Office Web Apps Server.

Does it mean it should exclusively be used only for office web app server or can I use the same server to host my provider hosted app's web site.

Thanks
DNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOS/WAC rebuild the metabase, which is why this isn't recommended, though if I recall as long as you're not using tcp 80/443/808/809 for your IIS Site, you can co-host. Likely fine for dev, but I'd suggest finding an alternate location for prod.

Comment: Thanks Trevor.. That explains why the default web site too got wiped out when I installed Office Online Server.